# How to include CSS file in AMP project

Tags: amp-html

```
<style amp-custom>
{% include "style.css" %}
</style>
```

I am trying to create a simple AMP-site and got some problem. What is {% %}? It doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t reference external stylesheets **amp** pages, styles must be inlined under style tag with `amp-custom` attribute

```
<style amp-custom>

</style>
```

reference: [amp styling doc](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/style_pages)

Answer (score 7):

You can try it, it's working for me...

```
<style amp-custom>
     @import url('css/custom.css');
</style>
```

Comment: using '@import' is invalid according to amp rules

Comment: Yes Akash, I know but I have no other options

Comment: But it will restrict AMP pages to get validated. I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`{% include "style.css" %}` is a twig tag (template). Are you by chance in WordPress or other php base framework ?

You have two possibilities:
 1. Using the include, you replace "style.css" with a reference to your css file to be include.
 2. You paste your css inside the `<style amp-custom>`, in place of the template tag (e.g. the whole `{% include "style.css" %}`).

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Try the following - 
include the specified css file during the execution of the php script

```
<style amp-custom>
    <?php include_once 'assets/css/all.css'; ?>
 </style>
```

Comment: Please add some explaination as to why your code snippet solves the problem. More info here: [answer]

Answer (score 0):

you can import the file as the stylesheet inherits from the css file. 
`@import "file/path/the/css/or/scss/file"` between the `<style amp-custom>` tag. the full code is below.

`<style amp-custom>
    @import "file/path/the/css/or/scss/file";
</style>`

[here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) is the reference.

Comment: The reference indicates this is now deprecated in favor of @use.

Answer (score 0):

If your technology is PHP then you can use the below syntax and it is working.

```
<style amp-custom>
 <?Php 
  $css  = file_get_contents('/amp/assets/css/header.css'); 
  echo $css; 
 ?>
</style>
```